# function argument as an input for f-string to change variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, f-string

```
def cleaning(input):
    name = str(input)
    read_file = pd.read_csv('#f"{name}".csv')
    print(read_file)

cleaning(InputKeyword)
```

My function must take an input keyword, and this will change the "name" to "#input" word.
I was trying with f-strigs, but it doesn't work. Any ideas or referrals where can I find the solution?
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: It's not good form to change the very nature of your question once you have answers, as it invalidates them. Rolled back. If you adopt my solution and there's a *different* problem that should really be a different question.

Comment: Try using `name = input()` and `pd.read_csv(f'#{name}.csv')`.

Answer (score 4):

```py
read_file = pd.read_csv('#f"{name}".csv')
```

That's not *actually* an f-string, it's a normal string that has an `f`, some quotes, and some braces *inside* it. An f-string must be *prefixed* with (surprisingly enough) an `f` :-)

I suggest you try something like:

```py
read_file = pd.read_csv(f"#{name}.csv")
```

If the `name` string holds `xyzzy`, this will try to process the file `#xyzzy.csv`.

Additionally, it's a *very* bad idea to use built-in functions as variable names. The `input` function is one such example. The following (complete) snippet solves both those issues:

```py
# Assumes file_base is a string, see below.
def cleaning(file_base):
    read_file = pd.read_csv(f"#{file_base}.csv")
    print(read_file)

cleaning("someString")
```

---

Note that you can put *arbitrary* expressions inside f-strings, not just variable names. Hence there's no need to create `name` as a separate (named) object, you could just insert `str(file_base)` inside the braces.

However, for your particular case, I don't think the use of `str(file_base}` is necessary since it appears from tour comments that `file_base` is *already* a string, and I believe the formatting for a string without a `format_spec` is just the string itself<sup>(a)</sup>.

This is why I have `f"#{file_base}.csv"` in the code above *without* a `str()` around the `file_base` variable.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> For objects in general, an `{object}` snippet inside an f-string will call the object's `__format__()` method, passing in the `format_spec` used. Hence `f"{something:314159}` would use the object method call `something.__format__("314159")` to format the object into a string.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I fixed the code. And yes, the name of the file is #name.csv

Comment: The function still does not work.     NameError: name 'input' is not defined.

Comment: user16133525: [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is the name of a built-in function and `str(input)` → `'<built-in function input>'`.

Comment: @user16133525: see the second part of my answer, `input` is a Python built-in function that you should not be using.

Comment: Oh great, thank you! The only thing, I need to do cleaning(InputKeyword="mykeyword") to make it work

Comment: @user16133525, keep in mind that `cleaning(InputKeyword="mykeyword")` will set the `InputKeyword` parameter to `"mykeyword"`, meaning you'll need `def cleaning(InputKeyword)` - the names must match if you use *named* parameters. Or you could simply pass the *positional* parameter `"mykeyword"`.

Comment: Is it even necessary to use `str(file_base)`?  Won't the f-string formatter automatically call `str` for you if necessary?

Comment: Good point, @Mark, I just blindly copied in the expression from the OP. Have adjusted answer to add that in.

Comment: And a nice adjustment it was too.  I like the way you expanded on my comment.

Comment: For `{obj}`'s evaluation in an f-string, first `type(obj).__format__(obj, "")` is tried then it falls back to `__str__` and then `__repr__`. For a string `obj`, first two give the same result but your last paragraph seems to be mentioning a generic `obj` so I thought this might be worth mentioning...

Comment: @MustafaAydın, thanks greatly for the education, I'm almost always open to making improvements based on suggestions. I've adjusted the answer to incorporate your comments, feel free to educate me even more if you still see any shortcomings.

Comment: Oh, who am I to educate, thanks for the answer.